# Howto look up an SRV record pointing to an IPv6 address

Tags: c++, linux, dns, ipv6, srv

My C++ application has to lookup a DNS SRV record pointing to an IPv6 address. From what I researched so far, the res_search() family of functions is the way to go.

Does anyone have an example how to prepare such a query and how to extract the IPv6 result ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`res_search()` (or `req_query`) is probably the way to go to obtain the initial `SRV` record.

However the `SRV` record can only contain a *hostname*, not a literal IPv6 address.

You should feed the hostname contents of that record into the `getaddrinfo()` function which can then look up both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses at the same time.

Comment: +1 - `SRV` records include a resource name.  It is the user's responsibility to resolve the name to an IP address or whatever using additional queries (e.g., `A` or `AAAA`) or other system calls.

Comment: @D.Shawley: Although, I believe its possible for the DNS server to push the lookup as an extra record in the results.

Comment: @ZanLynx It's possible, but certainly not required.

Comment: @Alnitak: Right. But its worth looking for the record in the DNS response before making a new request.

Comment: @ZanLynx no, not really, IMHO.  The original answer might only include an `A` record even though both `A` and `AAAA` exist.

Comment: @Alnitak: And it might contain a `AAAA` record too. Why not?

Comment: @ZanLynx that's my point - until you've explicitly asked you don't actually know for certain. Extra information supplied by the recursive resolve in the _Additional Section_ should not be relied on, and may be incomplete.